# How to Get the Attachment Type in an Outlook email using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

i want to save the attachments of any outlook email into my local system along with their types (.text,   .png, .jpeg) 
how can i know the attachment type in C#

with regards,
vishnu

Answer (score 1):

Read the Attachment.FileName property and extract the extension.